# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'drone_0002_01320.jpg' -> 'drone_0002_01320.png'

Tags: python, operating-system

I'm trying to rename a set of files using the following code. The File is within the folder but it gives the following error. My code is attached here with:

```
import os
path='absolute_path'
arr = os.listdir(path)

for i in arr:
    old_name=i
    old_name_part=old_name.split(".")
    new_name=old_name_part[0]+".png"
    print(i,'\t',old_name,'\t',new_name)
    os.rename(i,new_name)
```

Error :

```
drone_0002_01320.jpg     drone_0002_01320.jpg    drone_0002_01320.png
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/absolute_path/rename.py", line 23, in <module>
    os.rename(i,new_name)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'drone_0002_01320.jpg' -> 'drone_0002_01320.png'
```

Comment: You should believe your computer. If it says the file is not there, then it is not there. You say it _"is within the folder"_ - which folder? It is probably supposed to be in a different folder. Or it is simply not there ;)

Comment: figured it out  : folder.os.rename(path+i,path+new_name), is not it takes the current location as the file path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.rename(i,new_name)` takes the full path of your file

you can change it into this:
`os.rename(os.path.join(path, i),os.path.join(path, new_name))`

Consider read about `pathlib` module, it has some good function for those kind of problems

Comment: `os.rename` can work just fine with relative paths, you just have to know what it is relative to.

Comment: @zvone you are right, but if you explicitly concat those path, it will be right for sure :)

Comment: True, your solution seems to be right. I just don't want readers to be misguided, so I corrected the mistake.